# Автоматическая отправка csr

Tags: сертификат, x509certificate, grpc

В текущем проекте имеется *grpc* сервер и клиенты которые должны удовлетворять *mutual tls*. Клиенты создают *csr*, чтобы *CA* их подписал. Сейчас не используются сторонние решения *CA* - просто питоновский скрипт, который сипользует модуль *cryptography*. На данном этапе приходится **вручную** отправлять *csr* к *CA* и подписанный сертификат к клиенту обратно. Если клиентов много, то это становится неудобным.

Я новичок в этой теме и пытаюсь найти удобное решение. Конечно можно добавить еще один сервер на *CA*, который будет принимать *csr* и потравлять их обратно. Но это выглядит, как сильное усложнение, возможно есть готовые решения со всей инфраструктурой, или какая то общепринятая схема.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения банальной эрудиции автоматическое подписание клиентских сертификатов - злющее зло. Как ваш CA будет верифицировать запросы? Как минимум проверять, что указанные в запросе люди существуют?

Если вас этот вопрос не беспокоит, то оберните ваш CA в веб-сервер, а клиентам раздайте приложение, которое будет конструировать CSR, отправлять его POST-запросом на сервер и в ответ принимать подписанный сертификат.